# Cannot login into WAMP server page

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I am using WAMP server for php.

I wrote a HTML/PHP snippet and it's working fine,

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But now whenever I type localhost in my address bar and press  enter, instead of wamp server page it runs the same HTML script.

Please let me know how can I get WAMP page back. 
Thanks!

Comment: Did u try restarting the wamp server

Comment: Yeah!! I did. But it's still not working.

Comment: Did you overwrite \wamp\www\index.php or change any <virtualHost> settings in `httpd.conf`

Comment: Oh Yeah!! I moved a file named index.php to recycle bin. I moved it back to www now. It's working fine now.!!! Thanks. Although can anybody tell me the use of this file?

Comment: Its just a configuration file for apache server.By modifying this file you could control the way apache server works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrote the \wamp\www\index.php file. This is the home server page of WAMP. You should rather make directories for each project and move your files in there, that way you can access them from the WAMP server page.